# Sample JSONX to XML with multiple entry tags

Tags: xml, xslt

First of all, I thank very much, as this forum really helps for learners. I need your help again

I am trying to transform jsonx to regular xml, few things I need to do here is

1)The output xml should be in "feed" tag and  if there are multiple entry tags coming in then href link(at the end), it should append the count of entry like as as shown below)

2)If one entry feild is coming the request, then my xml should like below

3)If the Authorization name changes to Authentication then at the end of the href link, only the last part will change to authentication.

Sample Jsonx coming with multiple entry tags

```
<json:object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd">
    <json:array name="entry">
        <json:object>
            <json:object name="content">
                <json:object name="Authorization"> <!--whenever this feild name changes, then the output xml should append this in href as shown in xml" -->
                    <json:object name="authorizedPeriod">
                        <json:string name="duration">0</json:string>
                        <json:string name="start">0</json:string>
                    </json:object>
                    <json:object name="publishedPeriod">
                        <json:string name="duration">0</json:string>
                        <json:string name="start">0</json:string>
                    </json:object>
                    <json:string name="accessToken">688b026c-665f-4994-9139-6b21b13fbeee</json:string>
                    <json:string name="status">1</json:string>
                    <json:string name="expires_in">31536000</json:string>
                    <json:string name="refresh_token">9b853368-f7c3-4a35-a0f3-6c406611eaa6</json:string>
                    <json:string name="thirdParty">data_custodian_admin</json:string>
                </json:object>
            </json:object>
            <json:string name="published">2014-05-12T13:02:03Z</json:string>
            <json:string name="updated">2014-05-12T13:02:03Z</json:string>
        </json:object>
        <json:object>
            <json:object name="entry">
                <json:object name="content">
                    <json:object name="Authorization">
                        <json:object name="authorizedPeriod">
                            <json:string name="duration">0</json:string>
                            <json:string name="start">0</json:string>
                        </json:object>
                        <json:object name="publishedPeriod">
                            <json:string name="duration">0</json:string>
                            <json:string name="start">0</json:string>
                        </json:object>
                        <json:string name="accessToken">809caf03-612e-4e89-94b1-6f86d83b1ef</json:string>
                        <json:string name="status">1</json:string>
                        <json:string name="expires_in">31536000</json:string>
                        <json:string name="refresh_token">9b853368-f7c3-4a35-a0f3-6c406611eaa6</json:string>
                        <json:string name="thirdParty">upload_admin</json:string>
                    </json:object>
                </json:object>
                <json:string name="published">2014-05-12T13:02:03Z</json:string>
                <json:string name="updated">2014-05-12T13:02:03Z</json:string>
            </json:object>
        </json:object>
    </json:array>
</json:object>
```

Need to convert it like below xml when request has multiple entry tags

```
  <feed xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <id>urn:uuid:2215a7c7-29be-455a-bc5e-bbe1ecfcb089</id>
        <title>Green Button Usage Feed</title>
        <updated>2014-09-04T16:19:38-07:00</updated>
        <link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization" rel="self"/>
        <entry> 
         <id>urn:uuid:D1A987DA-F5AC-468B-9C03-FA7839BCC8F1</id>
              <link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization" rel="up"/>
              <link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization/1" rel="self"/>  <!-- for every one entry tag, the number at the end of the url  should increase by 1 and for the second entry tag the number should change to 2 as below -->
              <content>
                <Authorization> <!-- if the "Authorization" element changes, then in the href link  only the last part changes for ex: if element comes as Authentication then the href link will change to "https://services.org/resource/Authentication" -->

                    <authorizedPeriod>
                        <duration>0</duration>
                        <start>0</start>
                    </authorizedPeriod>
                    <publishedPeriod>
                        <duration>0</duration>
                        <start>0</start>
                    </publishedPeriod>
                    <accessToken>688b026c-665f-4994-9139-6b21b13fbeee</accessToken>
                    <status>1</status>
                    <expires_in>31536000</expires_in>
                    <refresh_token>9b853368-f7c3-4a35-a0f3-6c406611eaa6</refresh_token>

                    <thirdParty>data_custodian_admin</thirdParty>
                </Authorization>
            </content>
            <published>2014-05-12T13:02:03Z</published>
            <updated>2014-05-12T13:02:03Z</updated>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <id>urn:uuid:D1A987DA-F5AC-468B-9C03-FA7839BCC8F1</id>
              <link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization" rel="up"/>
              <link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization/2" rel="self"/>  <!-- since this is second entry tag, number is changed to 2, only number will chnage the rest of the url is allways constant-->
            <content>
                    <Authorization>
                        <authorizedPeriod>
                            <duration>0</duration>
                            <start>0</start>
                        </authorizedPeriod>
                        <publishedPeriod>
                            <duration>0</duration>
                            <start>0</start>
                        </publishedPeriod>
                        <accessToken>809caf03-612e-4e89-94b1-6f86d83b1ef8</accessToken>
                        <status>1</status>
                        <expires_in>31536000</expires_in>
                        <refresh_token>9b853368-f7c3-4a35-a0f3-6c406611eaa6</refresh_token>
                        <thirdParty>upload_admin</thirdParty>
                    </Authorization>
                </content>
                <published>2014-05-12T13:02:03Z</published>
                <updated>2014-05-12T13:02:03Z</updated>
            </entry>
    </feed>
```

Need to convert xml as below when only one single entry tag comes in

```
<feed xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <id>urn:uuid:2215a7c7-29be-455a-bc5e-bbe1ecfcb089</id>
        <title>Green Button Usage Feed</title>
        <updated>2014-09-04T16:19:38-07:00</updated>
        <link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization" rel="self"/>
        <entry> 
         <id>urn:uuid:D1A987DA-F5AC-468B-9C03-FA7839BCC8F1</id>
              <link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization" rel="up"/>
              <link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization/1" rel="self"/>  <!-- for every one entry tag, the number at the end of the url  should increase by 1 and for the second entry tag the number should change to 2 as below -->
              <content>
                <Authorization> <!-- if the "Authorization" element changes, then in the href link  only the last part changes for ex: if element comes as Authentication then the href link will change to "https://services.org/resource/Authentication" -->

                    <authorizedPeriod>
                        <duration>0</duration>
                        <start>0</start>
                    </authorizedPeriod>
                    <publishedPeriod>
                        <duration>0</duration>
                        <start>0</start>
                    </publishedPeriod>
                    <accessToken>688b026c-665f-4994-9139-6b21b13fbeee</accessToken>
                    <status>1</status>
                    <expires_in>31536000</expires_in>
                    <refresh_token>9b853368-f7c3-4a35-a0f3-6c406611eaa6</refresh_token>

                    <thirdParty>data_custodian_admin</thirdParty>
                </Authorization>
            </content>
            <published>2014-05-12T13:02:03Z</published>
            <updated>2014-05-12T13:02:03Z</updated>
        </entry>
    </feed>
```

here is my XLST( iam not sure how to use for loop and appending the count to href link at the end.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
    xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" 
    xmlns:dpfunc="http://www.datapower.com/extensions/functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="dp" 
    extension-element-prefixes="dp dpconfig dpfunc date">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">


        <!-- Generate variables-->
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrentTime" select="date:date-time()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vRandomSalt" select="dp:generate-uuid()"/>
        <!-- create the AI node -->
        <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <id>urn:uuid:<xsl:value-of select="$vRandomSalt"/>
            </id>
            <title>Datausage</title>
            <updated>
                <xsl:value-of select="$vCurrentTime"/>
            </updated>
            <link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization/Authorization" rel="self"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
        </feed>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start instead of using `<xsl:copy-of select="." />` in your main template, you need to do this:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates />
```

This allows you to then use template matching to manipulate all your json tags. For the first of such templates, you would need a template to match `json:array` objects:

```
<xsl:template match="json:array" priority="2">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json:object" />
</xsl:template>
```

In this case, just skip over them, and select the child `json:object` which you will then transform to `entry` elements in this next template, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="json:array/json:object" priority="2">
    <xsl:element name="{../@name}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

        <!-- More code here -->

        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

(Note how it gets the name `entry` from the parent array, to avoid hard-coded the word `entry` itself)

It is in the `<!-- More code here -->` bit you would output the `id` and `link` elements for each 
`entry`. In particular, the second `link` would be output like so:

```
<link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization/{position()}" rel="self"/>
```

Notice the use of Attribute Value Templates here to output the number. The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

EDIT: To make it dependent on a descendant object, it could look like this

```
<link href="https://services.org/resource/{.//json:object[@name='content']/json:object/@name}" rel="up"/>
```

(It might be worth putting the expression in a variable first though)

Finally, you would have a more general template, to manipulate other json elements

```
<xsl:template match="json:*[@name]">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
```

(Note that the first two templates were given a priority to ensure they got used ahead of this general template)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
    xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" 
    xmlns:dpfunc="http://www.datapower.com/extensions/functions"
    xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    exclude-result-prefixes="dp" 
    extension-element-prefixes="dp dpconfig dpfunc date">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- Generate variables-->
    <xsl:variable name="vCurrentTime" select="date:date-time()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vRandomSalt" select="dp:generate-uuid()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- create the AI node -->
        <feed xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <id>urn:uuid:<xsl:value-of select="$vRandomSalt" /></id>
            <title>Datausage</title>
            <updated>
                <xsl:value-of select="$vCurrentTime"/>
            </updated>
            <link href="https://services.org/resource/Authorization" rel="self"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </feed>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="json:array" priority="2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json:object" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="json:array/json:object" priority="2">
        <xsl:element name="{../@name}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
            <id>urn:uuid:<xsl:value-of select="$vRandomSalt" /></id>
            <xsl:variable name="type" select=".//json:object[@name='content']/json:object/@name" />
            <link href="https://services.org/resource/{$type}" rel="up"/>
            <link href="https://services.org/resource/{$type}/{position()}" rel="self"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="json:*[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the namespace for `json` has to be defined in the XSLT too.

Comment: Thanks very much for the XSLT..I really appreciate the help...one more quick quick question.

Comment: Thanks very much for the XSLT..I really appreciate the help...one more quick quick question. Lets say if request comes has Authentication(after content tag) tag instead if Authorization, then how can I change the end part of href like "https://services.org/resource/Authorization/Authentication"

Comment: I've made an edit which shows it could be done, if I understood it right! If not, it might lead you in the right direction, at least...

Comment: If you have a situation where the XSLT is not quite working, it is best to amend your original question to show this. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Tim, did not understand... Sorry